# Why LINQ Distinct() does not preserve order list?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two columns as `Date` and `PersonInCharge`, I want to sort the list by descending by date then return the list of ONLY person's name without duplicates. I used `Distinct()` to filter the final name list but I don't know why the list order is always alphabetical instead of descending date.

Here is my code so far:

```
  IList<string> model.StaffNames = await _context.FarmDiary
    .Select(f => new { f.PersonInCharge, f.Date })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
    .Select(x => x.PersonInCharge)
    .Distinct()
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: If this is Linq2Entities which resolves to some SQL-command it´s pure natural, as the order by-statement allways comes after any distinct or grouping. Anyway the order of the statements highly depends on the underlying linq-provider. For Linq2Objects one should expect order should be preserved.

Comment: In most DBMS distinct is implemented via ordering and comparing to the previous, which means distinct may overthrow any ordering you did previously. A reasonable approach by the provider would then be to ignore all orderings before the .Distinct() call (since .net .Distinct() does not guarantee preservation of order either they wouldn't even be inconsistent)

Comment: The query that is executed is simplified to `SELECT DISTINCT PersonInCharge FROM FarmDiary`. Since distinct can use indexes to speed up the query, the order of results will depend on the indexes available (for reasons see other comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distinct() is about returning distinct rows, it doesn't promise any order but still orders on what it operates. For ordering there is OrderBy, OrderByDescending. In your case, since there is no Date in your final list, you cannot order by date.

EDIT:

```
void Main()
{
    List<FarmDiary> farmDiary = new List<FarmDiary> {
        new FarmDiary{Id=1, PersonInCharge="Bob",Date=new DateTime(2018,6,1)},
        new FarmDiary{Id=2, PersonInCharge="John",Date=new DateTime(2018,6,2)},
        new FarmDiary{Id=3, PersonInCharge="Bob",Date=new DateTime(2018,6,15)},
        new FarmDiary{Id=4, PersonInCharge="David",Date=new DateTime(2018,7,1)},
        new FarmDiary{Id=5, PersonInCharge="Zachary",Date=new DateTime(2018,6,10)},
    };

    List<string> staffNames = farmDiary
    .GroupBy(d => d.PersonInCharge)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.OrderByDescending(d => d.Date).First().Date)
    .Select(x => x.Key)
    .ToList();

    staffNames.Dump();
}

public class FarmDiary
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PersonInCharge { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So is there any solution in my case to achieve it?

Comment: after the select, you could use .GroupBy(x=>x.PersonInCharge).Select(x=>x.FirstOrDefault()).OrderByDescending(x=>x.Date).Select(x=>x.PersonInCharge).ToListAsync(); (or something along those lines; GroupBy().FirstOrDefault() is a workaround for the lack of a .DistinctBy() method)

Comment: @HoàngNguyễn, I edited my message to show a solution, actually based somewhat on DevilSuichiro's comment.

Comment: Yep, @DevilSuichiro's solution works fine, I don't need to manipulate model, but thank you anyway.

Comment: @HoàngNguyễn, what do you mean by "I don't need to manipulate model"? The solution is above.

Comment: @CetinBasoz oh sorry, my bad, I did not mean anything, just ignore.